# Send OpenCV image in JSON from Python to Android

Tags: android, python, json, opencv

I have a Python server which operates on an image drawing something on it with OpenCV. After that I want to send the resultant image through a previously opened `socketserver` to an Android device. With the image I would also like to send a string, so I build a JSON object to be sent. The object received by the Android app contains both elements but the image is the string representation of an OpenCV `Mat` object.
I couldn't find any method on how to convert that kind of representation of the image in `byte` array so that I could rebuild in the Android app the image and display it.

How can I send the image correctly and then converted in the Android app?

Here is my Python script for build the image, the JSON and send it:

```
imgou = numpy.zeros((numpy.size(mat_image, 0), numpy.size(mat_image, 1), 3), numpy.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(imgou, cont, idx, (0,255,0), 3)

print "build json"
outjson = {}
outjson['img'] = numpy.array_str(imgou)
outjson['leaf'] = leaf
json_data = json.dumps(outjson)

self.request.sendall(json_data)
```

Here is the code of the Android app to process the JSON:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
...
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
String leaf_name = json.getString("leaf");
String mat_string = json.getString("img");

byte[] raw_data = mat_string.getBytes("utf-8");
Mat mat_img = new Mat();
mat_img.put(0, 0, raw_data);
```

At this point I should have in `mat_img` the `Mat` object ready to be written in a file and then displayed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [answer of Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34857184/send-opencv-image-in-json-from-python-to-android/34857567#34857567), I managed to pack the image in a JSON object and then retrive it from the Android application. Since OpenCV provides a method for `Bitmap` to `Mat` conversion, sending the image instead of the `Mat` object si more handy.

Here the working code of the Python server:

```
img_file = open("image1.png", "r")

# read the image file
data = img_file.read()        

# build JSON object
outjson = {}
outjson['img'] = data.encode('base64')   # data has to be encoded base64 and decode back in the Android app base64 as well
outjson['leaf'] = "leaf"
json_data = json.dumps(outjson)

# close file pointer and send data
img_file.close()
self.request.sendall(json_data)
```

Here the working code of the Android app:

```
// Read JSON from socket inputstream and rebuild the string
InputStream in = so.getInputStream();
if (in == null) return false;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
sb = new StringBuilder();

String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   sb.append(line);
}

...
// Convert string in JSON and retrieve raw data
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
String leaf_name = json.getString("leaf");
String mat_string = json.getString("img");

// Convert raw byte data of image into Bitmap image
FileOutputStream byteBuffer = new FileOutputStream();

byte[] raw_data = Base64.decode(mat_string, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(raw_data, 0, raw_data.length);
img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteBuffer);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

form your server you can send the image into a byte array
now in your android app you can recive the byte array and convert it into bitmap and then into Mat

```
byte[] bitmapdata = Base64.decode("your byte string", Base64.DEFAULT);
//here the data coming from server is assumed in Base64
//if you are sending bytes in plain string you can directly convert it to byte array
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapdata, 0,        bitmapdata.length);

//android OpenCv function
org.opencv.android.Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap,mat);
```

Comment: My question is more about: how can I convert the image into a byte array and pack it into a JSON? Otherwise it would be the perfect way the one you propose